# iOS - Best way to add rows to a UITableView with a delay?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delay

I am trying to make an iOS very similar to the game [Lifeline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFEcWiBtEUs)

The game looks as though it's just a table view that has a row inserted after a delay.

I have managed to insert rows like this

```
 for obj in array {
                    self.dialogue.append(obj)
                    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
                    self.tableView.endUpdates()
                    }}
```

*Note the self.dialogue is my data source for my table view.

However I do not know how to add a delay in between adding a new row, for example

-> Insert row -> Wait 3 seconds-> Insert another row

How can I do this like it's done in the game?

Answer (score 0):

you may implement separate method or block for inserting the rows and call it from inside your for loop with delay. e.g.

```
var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) 

for obj in array {
  dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
    self.dialogue.append(obj)
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
  })
}}
```